# Flask with WSGI cannot fetch data in certain portions of application

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

In one part of my application, I am fetching and transferring an object which is supposed to be looped into on the main page.

so this is the code

the route:

```
@mod_site.route("/test/new", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def createTest():
    if session.get("user") == True and session['type'] == "admin" :
        from app.models.Batch import Batch
        batches = Batch.query.all()
        if request.method == "POST" :
            return "adding test"
        return render_template("admin/test/create_test.html", batches = batches)
```

and this is the html form I created where I want to iterate through the object "Batch":

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" /><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" placeholder="date" /><br><br>
    <label for="batch">Select Batch: &nbsp;</label>
    <select name="batch" id="batch">
        {% for batch in batches %}
        <option value="{{batch.id}}">{{batch.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select><br><br>
    <h4>Select Students:</h4>
    <div id="loadStudents"></div>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="type of test" /><br><br>

    <button>Confirm test</button>
</form>
```

Now, This code works properly on my local machine while running on native flask env. But there is some problem with it while running with apache and mod_WSGI. I also checked the error log of apache2, and this is the error I found a lot:

> [Tue Apr 17 01:39:41.693338 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 3301] [client 90.88.35.197:58322] mod_wsgi (pid=3301): Request data read error when proxying data to daemon process: Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete.

I cannot understand why this is happening, as other parts of website are working great with the db except for this.

Answer (score 0):

That error message would occur where the HTTP client dropped the connection while still sending through the request content. How big is the request content? Are you dealing with unreliable client connections, such as over mobile data networks?

Comment: Right now, the site is in testing phase, so no, we are using a fairly decent connection. And the data I am trying to fetch is infact fetched in other parts of the application where it works with the same code!

Comment: It is not an issue with the application or the response from it. The problem is something to do with the request content sent by the client. It is failing to transfer that request content to the WSGI application process. Are you trying to use chunked request content or anything else strange like compressed request content? Is the request content length actually correct for what is sent? Are you using a secure connection?